# what is better? using iframe or something like jquery to load an html file in external website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, external

I want my customers create their own HTML on my web application and copy and paste my code to their website to showing the result in the position with customized size and another options in page that they want. the output HTML of my web application contain HTML tags and JavaScript codes (for example is a web chart that created with javascript).

I found two way for this. one using `iframe` and two using `jquery .load()`.

**What is better and safer? Is there any other way?**

Comment: fancybox is good option, but it also depends on your needs and your choice... I don't think it will make performance issues for your application

Comment: If i was doing to do it... I would go for JQuery

Answer (score 2):

`iframe` is better - if you are running Javascript then that script shouldn't execute in the same context as your user's sites: you are asking for a level of trust here that the user shouldn't need to accede to, and your code is all nicely sandboxed so you don't have to worry about the parent document's styles and scripts.

As a front-end web developer and webmaster I've often taken the decision myself to sandbox third-party code in iframes. Below are some of the reasons I've done so:

- Script would play with the DOM of the document. Once a third-party widget took it upon itself to introduce buggy and performance-intensive PNG fix hacks for IE across every PNG used in `img` tags and CSS across our site.
- Many scripts overwrite the global `onload` event, robbing other scripts of their initialisation trigger.
- Reading local session info and sending it back to their own repositories.
- Loading any number of resources and perform CPU-intensive processes, interrupting and weighing down my site's core experience.

The above are all examples of short-sightedness or malice on the part of the third parties you may see yourself as above, but the point is that as one of your service's users I shouldn't need to take a gamble. If I put your code in an iframe, I know it can happily do its own thing and not screw with my site or its users. I can also choose to delay load and execution to a moment of my choosing (by dynamically loading the iframe at a moment of choice).

To argue the point in terms of your convenience rather than the users':

- You don't have to worry about any of the trust issues associated with XSS. You can honestly tell your users they're not exposing themselves to any unnecessary worry by running your tool.
- You don't have to make the extra effort to circumvent the effects of CSS and JS on your users' sites.